# Unable to add data connection. Could not find any resources appropriate for the specifield culture or the neutral culture

Tags: c#

I have a project and a database. after I put the project and database on a virtual machine and then connect to a newly created database on the virtual server, I get an error like this.I use visual studio version 2019 and sql server ssms18. can someone help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9VmL.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you b should dll in picture near your exe.
If it's copied maybe problem of 86/64 bit versions

Comment: I don't understand your answer and I am also looking for an answer for this same question

Comment: so what is 86/64 bit for? Visual or SQL server or windows version. I don't quite understand your answer but I appreciate it and am still looking forward to another answer to this problem.

Comment: Well sometimes you use some libraries in your c# app it may contain some native libs created by c++. So when you run your app in another pc(here vm) you may encounter some running error despite you copied all dlls near your exe.

Comment: @Xuan-Lap Try this in your solution explorer project: right click on your resource file: "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer" and select properties. and in properties of this resource file, in Build Action property, set value to "Embedded Resource". Compile it again and copy whole files in your virtual machine again. If it will works, tell me to convert it to answer and make it as answered

Comment: Do you mean the properties of file resources.resx? if it's that file, then I have Embedded Resource available. or is it properties of all files in the project??

Comment: No just properties of file "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer.SqlViewSupport.xml"  set to as I mentioned in previous comment and compile whole project and remove project from virtual machine and copy all new compile from your pc to vm.

Comment: hi  bud,  i really appreciate your help and explanation. but my project seems to have no" Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer.SqlViewSupport.xml" file. but i changed all connection strings in my project properties and it worked. It's not what I wanted, but it worked well